# vscode open file browser function

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm looking to call the open file/folder functionality from the screenshot below from within an extension so a user can easily select a file without having to open it in a workspace.

[image]

Also similar to this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bodil.file-browser

Can anyone point me in the direction of the function name or something similar?

Is this exposed public yet?

Ben

Answer (score 0):

I mainly found the answer with the showOpenDialog, but it doesn't seem to have a modal option, which would be nice.

```
File Picker# 
Extensions can use the vscode.window.showOpenDialog API to open the system file picker and select files or folders.
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/common-capabilities#file-picker